Returned server for api route and version on docker?
I'm unsure why my docker-compose file is throwing this error, i've got four services being spun up the control centre, schema-registery, zookeeper and a broker. The only one that threw up an error was the zookeeper.
which was
request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2FdockerDesktopLinuxEngine/v1.46/images/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0/json, check if the server supports the requested API version 

the zookeeper definition that i've done is:
zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
      hostname: zookeeper
      container_name: zookeeper
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      healthcheck:
        test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      networks:
        - confluent

my full docker compose file is:
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
      hostname: zookeeper
      container_name: zookeeper
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      healthcheck:
        test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      networks:
        - confluent

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", 'nc -z localhost 9092' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.4.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.4.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
      schema-registry:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONFLIENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9021/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

networks: confluent

What my understanding is that maybe there is not zookeeper 7.4.0 available as a dockerimage on confluent network, am i correct in thinking of those lines or is there something simpler?

Just copy/pasted your docker-compose file, first thing that I ran into is that networks: confluent should be a mapping, i.e.: networks: <newline><indent>confluent:.
Besides that, this might be a docker problem, not specific to your docker-compose. Have you seen this post?

FWIW: I've run your docker-compose file on my machine (Docker installed on Windows 11 under WSL) and all containers run as they should, I did not get any error. After everything had started I was able to visit the control center at http://localhost:9021

@SaaruLindestøkke i realised its because of my laptop, it was relatively cheap and when these containers spin up, it takes away all the memory on my computer, once i deleted stuff. The docker compose is working fine now but again its my hardwares memory. Now its hanging up on starting the control center

Control Center is causing that issue... Remove it, and try a different kafka UI if you need it. You also don't need Zookeeper. Use the official native Kafka image. It requires much less memory and storage
